# Routing to specific URLs with prefilled form inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a scaffold called `Places` and I want each `place` to have a form with string fields called `location` and `name`. The issue is that I need the routing to take the user to the form for a specific location.

Example: www.example.com/places/location1 would take the user to the signup form for Location 1 with the `location` form field prefilled with "Location 1"

The form fields between each location are exactly the same EXCEPT for the location name in the `location` field.

What is the best way to approach this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is NOT to use a scaffold as you want a different behavior. Rails scaffold will generate your routes with `resources places`, and `/places/ID` is already taken. If you want to keep the scaffold, you should probably add a custom action to your controller, and define a route for that.

You should add something like this in your `routes.rb` file

```
get '/location/%loc_name', to: 'places_controller#prefill_location'
```

Then define the action in `places_controller.rb`

```
def prefill_location
  # This is mostly a guess, I am not too sure if I understood what you want to do
  @place = Place.new(location: params[:loc_name])
  render 'new'
end
```